# SQL Server CTE doesn't Join Properly

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, common-table-expression

The data for this project contains two columns with semicolon-delimited strings. These are actually ordered pairs. So, for example, in: "a;b;c", "x;y;z", 'a' is paired with 'x'. The goal for our query is to create a table where this relationship is clearly represented one row at a time.

Here is a script to re-create the sample data:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.sampleData;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.lookupCPT;
GO

CREATE TABLE sampleData 
(
    numRow bigint IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_numRow PRIMARY KEY,
    sDelimQty varchar(MAX) NULL,
    sDelimCPT varchar(MAX) NULL
)

CREATE TABLE lookupCPT 
(
    numRow bigint IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_numRowCPT PRIMARY KEY,
    sCPTCode varchar(10) NULL,
    decCPTRate decimal(16,2) NULL
)

INSERT [dbo].[lookupCPT] ([numRow], [sCPTCode], [decCPTRate]) 
VALUES (1, N'123', CAST(4.00 AS Decimal(16, 2)))

INSERT [dbo].[lookupCPT] ([numRow], [sCPTCode], [decCPTRate]) 
VALUES (2, N'456', CAST(5.00 AS Decimal(16, 2)))

INSERT [dbo].[lookupCPT] ([numRow], [sCPTCode], [decCPTRate]) 
VALUES (3, N'789', CAST(7.00 AS Decimal(16, 2)))

INSERT [dbo].[sampleData] ([numRow], [sDelimQty], [sDelimCPT]) 
VALUES (1, N'1;2', N'123;789')

INSERT [dbo].[sampleData] ([numRow], [sDelimQty], [sDelimCPT]) 
VALUES (2, N'3', N'456')
```

We attempted to accomplish this using common table expressions:

```
WITH Qty_CTE (numRowQ, Qty) AS
(
    SELECT numRow, value
    FROM sampleData
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(sDelimQty, ';')
),
CPT_CTE (numRowC, CPT) AS
(
    SELECT numRow, value
    FROM sampleData
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(sDelimCPT, ';')
)
SELECT * 
FROM sampleData 
JOIN CPT_CTE c on c.numRowC = sampleData.numRow
JOIN Qty_CTE q on q.numRowQ = sampleData.numRow
```

However, doing this doubles the amount of rows in our output:

[q1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrsSP.png)

But, if we remove either one of the two joins, it returns correctly:

[q2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvlim.png)

Any ideas? Thanks very much

After all the helpful answers, below is the final solution. Cheers!

```
WITH Qty_CTE (numRowQ, Qty, RN) AS
(
    SELECT 
        numRow, value, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RN
    FROM 
        sampleData
    CROSS APPLY 
        STRING_SPLIT(sDelimQty, ';')
),
CPT_CTE (numRowC, CPT, CPTRate, RN) AS
(
    SELECT 
        s.numRow, value as CPT, l.decCPTRate as CPTRate, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RN
    FROM 
        sampleData s
    CROSS APPLY 
        STRING_SPLIT(sDelimCPT, ';')
    JOIN 
        lookupCPT l ON value = l.sCPTCode
)
SELECT 
    numRow, sDelimCPT, sDelimQty, CPT, CPTRate, Qty, CPTRate * Qty as Total
FROM 
    sampleData 
JOIN 
    CPT_CTE c on c.numRowC = sampleData.numRow
JOIN 
    Qty_CTE q on q.numRowQ = sampleData.numRow AND c.RN = q.RN
```

Comment: are the delimited numbers *always* in ascending order?

Comment: not a guarantee unfortunately :-\

Comment: for me, q1 is logical as well as q2.

Comment: What you have is expected (when you think a bout cardinality)? With `numRow=1`, the first CTE produce 2 rows, and multiply with the 2 rows the second CTE produce, you got the number of rows that should be. To eliminate the extra row, you need to have a way to corresponse the rows created by two CTEs.

Comment: Sebas, could you please explain your reasoning? thanks a lot

Comment: DVT, the field we're using to correspond all the records is numRow: this exists as numRow in the sampleData table and as numRowC and numRowQ in the two CTEs, respectively.

Comment: @mikemorris In q1, if you take a way the rows with numRow=2 and the part from sample data, you got a CROSS JOIN of Qty_CTE (except numRow=2) and CPT_CTE(numRow=2). That 's what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `STRING_SPLIT` function preserve order, then this will work.

```
WITH Qty_CTE (numRowQ, Qty, RN) AS
(
SELECT numRow, value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RN
FROM sampleData
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(sDelimQty, ';')
),
CPT_CTE (numRowC, CPT, RN) AS
(
SELECT numRow, value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RN
FROM sampleData
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(sDelimCPT, ';')
)
SELECT * FROM sampleData 
JOIN CPT_CTE c on c.numRowC = sampleData.numRow
JOIN Qty_CTE q on q.numRowQ = sampleData.numRow AND c.RN = q.RN
```

Comment: Sorry, but the STRING_SPLIT function was actually part of the SQL Server 2016 release. Also, I tried this and ORDER BY SELECT NULL cannot be interpreted.

Comment: It should work now (I forgot the parentheses around SELECT NULL). About the STRING_SPLIT, either create one on your own or go over the manual of STRING_SPLIT to see if it is guaranteed.

Comment: No, I think you'll discover in the end that you actually didn't mean to want that. It's just my intuition.

Answer (score 0):

Both your examples q1 and q2 work as expected. `Qty_CTE` has a cardinality of 3 (Record 1 appears twice, record 2 appears once), so does `CPT_CTE`. 
`sampleData` has a cardinality of 2 (each row appears once only)

Since you're joining on the PK, sampleData x `Qty_CTE` x `CPT_CTE` should return 5 records, which it does (1x2x2 records for numrow 1 and 1x1x1 record for numrow 2). If you remove either `Qty_CTE` or `CPT_CTE` it should return 3 records, which it does (1x1x1 record for numrow 2 and 1x2 records for numrow 1).

We could propose a solution based on an expected result, if you had one.

Comment: I believe you are correct, but why does this happen:
sampleData x Qty_CTE x CPT_CTE?

Comment: Simple set theory. Simplisticly, each table will be computed according to your WHERE filters, in turns resulting into one *resultset*. Then, these resultsets will be combined with one another. In case of INNER JOIN, combination is *intersection*, therefore ending up being what I mentioned above.

Comment: Set A intersected with Set B with no condition at all will result into a A x B recordset. Sorry if I'm a bit clumsy explaining this but I realize I never had to do it :) I must practice

Comment: I think your problem might be that you're expecting each CTE to return 2 rows only. Please understand that STRING_SPLIT will duplicate numrow1 record in each CTE.